# How to create a directory named after the Year and Month

Tags: linux, terminal

So I want to create a directory called which is the Year + Month:

2021JAN

But in my terminal, I tried:

```
mkdir $(date + "%Y%m")
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
date: extra operand ‘%Y%m’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct command would be

```
mkdir $(date +"%Y%b")
```

or

```
mkdir `date +"%Y%b"`
```

Comment: is it possible to uppercase the month? JAN instead of Jan

Comment: @Maxxx, try add **^** symbol before **b**: `mkdir $(date +"%Y%^b")`. From [man](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html): **^      use upper case if possible**

Answer (score 1):

To create a directory with date try following command :

```
mkdir $(date +%Y%m)
```